# Trying to convert String S into String 1 and return 1 if true and false otherwise

Tags: java

I am trying to determine if it is possible to convert a given string S into String T by deleting some characters from S. My attempt so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Solution {
        public int solution(String S, String T) {

            int n = S.length();
            int m = T.length();

            boolean dp [][] = new boolean[n+1][m+1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<=m; j++){
                    dp[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            dp[0][0] = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < T.length(); j++){
                    if (dp[i][j]){
                        if(j<T.length() && (Character.toUpperCase(S.charAT(i)) == T.charAT(j)))
                        dp[i+1][j+1] = true;
                    if(!Character.isUpperCase(S.charAT(i)))
                    dp[i+1][j] = true;

                    }
                }
            }
            return (dp[n][m]);
            // write your code in Java SE 8
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with convert? How should it be converted? And what is the issue with your code, your question is unclear in several ways.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j<=m; j++){
                    dp[i][j] = false;
                }
            }  is useless

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

As `boolean`'s default value is `false` most of your `dp[][]` values are `false`.

In that case the following statement is useless

```
dp[i][j] = false;
```

Thus only `dp[0][0]` passes the following statement,

```
if (dp[i][j])
```

---

And there are many more problems in your code.

- You've mentioned the method's return type as `int` and trying to return a `boolean`.
- `charAT(i)` should be `charAt(i)` as Java is case sensitive.

---

As per your title *...return **1** if true and **false** otherwise*, you can't return two different data types from a single method. It should be either `boolean` or `int`. So it should be,

- ...return `1` if true and `0` otherwise
- ...return `true` if true and `false` otherwise

Comment: While all of this is true how is it an answer to the question? This looks more like a code review to me.

Comment: I've pointed out the mistakes so OP can figure things out. Because op's code seems a bit confusing to me, what she is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy problem, you don't need multiple lines code. Try this:

```
public boolean solution(String S, String T) {
    return S.contains(T);
}
```

From String API, contains method returns true if S string contains T string.

Edit: I made a mistake, your question said to **convert** a string S to A, this is another solution:

```
public boolean solution(String S, String T) {
     int charMet = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < T.length(); j++)
     if (S.charAt(i) == T.charAt(j)) charMet++;

     return charMet == T.length();
}
```

Comment: And how do you know that this is what it means to convert the string? What if S is "abcd" and T is "abd", wouldn't S be possible to convert then?